# What does configure function do in Kafka serializers / deserializers?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, deserialization

I am looking into implementing custom Serializers / Deserializers for Kafka. 
To implement a Kafka custom Serializer / Deserializer, we have to implement `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer` and `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer` respectively.

What I don't understand is the `configure(Map configs, boolean key)` method. What does it do? What should we pass into it? What is the purpose of this?

Most of the examples I came into, have not implemented anything inside the method. But I want to know what exactly this does. Not just ignore it.

Comment: If you look at the source code of String serializer or Confluent Avro serializer, they're configurable

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you. I will look into those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to implement a custom serializer, the configure method will be used to configure the serializer at the start. If you want to read more about the configure method kindly go through this link: https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serializer.html

> void configure​(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> configs,
> boolean isKey)

> Configure this class.
>
> Parameters:
> configs - configs in key/value pairs, isKey - whether is for key or value

Basically, the configure method accepts the Configurations Map as its first argument and second argument a boolean value, which sets true if it is for a Key or false if it is for value.

From there, these configurations can be stored as fields within de/serializer implementations and used as part of the de/serialize methods. For example, [`StringSerializer` has an `encoding` property](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.2/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringSerializer.java#L30).